# WordPress: cPanel password protect wp-admin generates too many redirects

Tags: wordpress, passwords, cpanel

I'm trying to use the built-in password protect option of cPanel to protect the wp-admin/ directory. The problem is that when I create the rule and associate an user to the newly created user, this actually generates an infine redirect sequence on that directory. Maybe it's because I'm already logged in, but I'm not sure. I don't actually know how this works in WP, but since I started writing articles for Smashing Magazine I know that this is possible because they use the same feature on their backend site. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.